# If $\mathrm{X}\in C(\mathrm{A}),\mathrm{X}\mathrm{A}=\mathrm{A}'\mathrm{X}$,then $\mathrm{X}$ is symmetrical.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\mathrm{A} \in \mathrm{M}_{n}(\mathbb{C})$, The minimal polynomial of $\mathrm{A}$ is equal to the characteristic polynomial of $\mathrm{A}$,$C(\mathrm{A})=\{\mathrm{B}:\mathrm{A}\mathrm{B}=
\mathrm{B}\mathrm{A}\}$.If $\mathrm{X}\in C(\mathrm{A}),\mathrm{X}\mathrm{A}=\mathrm{A}'\mathrm{X}$,then $\mathrm{X}$ is
symmetrical.

I think form the minimal polynomial of A
is equal to the characteristic polynomial of A,it can be deduced that
there is only one Jordan block belonging to eigenvalue $\lambda_{i}$,so the elementary divisors of $\mathrm{A}$ are mutually prime,then
$C(\mathrm{A})=P(\mathrm{A})=\{p(A):p(x)\in \mathbb{C}[x]\}$.
Doing this I don't know how to do it.

Comment: It means that the Jordan Blocks of $A$ correspond to different eigenvalues.

Comment: What is $A'$? Transpose? Conjugate transpose?

Comment: $\mathrm{A}'$ is transpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT

W.l.g. you can suppose that $A$ is in Jordan form. Then $X$ is in $C(A)=P(A)$ and therefore has the same 'block structure' as $A$.

We can therefore consider just a single block.

We have $AX=XA=A'X$ and so $(A-A')X=O$.

Can you now complete the proof?